# How to convert .pb files (protobuf files) to .weight files to use?

Tags: protocol-buffers, darknet, darkflow

I've trained a net using Darkflow and now have the .pb files. I was wondering if it's possible (and if it is, how can it be done) to convert the files to .weight files for Darknet? I'd like to use Darknet with these files to classify images on Raspberry Pi.

I've been Googling but I see most people want to do the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of weight file try `.pb`:

```
sudo ./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov2.cfg <yourfile>.pb data/dog.jpg
```

Comment: I didn't know they could be used in darknet, thanks!
Generating pb files seem to be broken in Darkflow though... just realized a few weeks ago.